# Power BI DAX Measure works for one column but not another

Tags: powerbi, dax

Using the information below I need to create a new table in DAX called Table ([Download a demo file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o8CRuQ2xhE0Qf6hOaDTwx6grFL3eqkaf/view?usp=sharing)).

I need to find the location of each employee (column "Name") at the time of the sale date in column "Sale Date" based on their contract details in table DbEmployees. If there is more than one valid contract for a given employee that the sale date fits in, use the shortest contract length.

My problem is that the below measure isn't working to generate column "Location", but it works just fine for column "new value".

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

[image]

Expected result:

| SaleID | EmployeeID | Sale Date | new value | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45643213 | 2021-02-04 | 89067445 | Sally Shore | 4 |
| 2 | 57647868 | 2020-04-15 | 57647868 | Paul Bunyon | 3 |
| 3 | 89067445 | 2019-09-24 | 57647868 | Paul Bunyon | 6 |

DbEmployees:

| ID | Name | StartDate | EndDate | Location | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 546465546 | Sandra Newman | 2021/01/01 | 2021/12/31 | 1 | Manager |
| 546465546 | Sandra Newman | 2020/01/01 | 2020/12/31 | 2 | Clerk |
| 546465546 | Sandra Newman | 2019/01/01 | 2019/12/31 | 3 | Clerk |
| 545365743 | Paul Bunyon | 2021/01/01 | 2021/12/31 | 6 | Manager |
| 545365743 | Paul Bunyon | 2020/04/01 | 2020/05/01 | 3 | Clerk |
| 545365743 | Paul Bunyon | 2019/04/01 | 2021/01/01 | 6 | Manager |
| 796423504 | Sally Shore | 2020/01/01 | 2020/12/31 | 4 | Clerk |
| 783546053 | Jack Tomson | 2019/01/01 | 2019/12/31 | 2 | Manager |

DynamicsSales:

| SaleID | EmployeeID | Sale Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45643213 | 2021/02/04 |
| 2 | 57647868 | 2020/04/15 |
| 3 | 89067445 | 2019/09/24 |

DynamicsContacts:

| EmployeeID | Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45643213 | Sandra Newman | sandra.newman@hotmail.com |
| 65437658 | Jack Tomson | jack.tomson@hotmail.com |
| 57647868 | Paul Bunyon | paul.bunyon@hotmail.com |
| 89067445 | Sally Shore | sally.shore@hotmail.com |

DynamicsAudit:

| SaleID | Changed Date | old value | new value | AuditID | Valid Until |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019/06/08 | 65437658 | 57647868 | 1 | 2020-06-07 |
| 1 | 2020/06/07 | 57647868 | 89067445 | 2 | 2021-05-07 |
| 1 | 2021/05/07 | 89067445 | 45643213 | 3 | 2021-05-07 |
| 2 | 2019/06/08 | 65437658 | 57647868 | 4 | 2020-06-07 |
| 2 | 2020/06/07 | 57647868 | 89067445 | 5 | 2021-05-07 |
| 2 | 2021/05/07 | 89067445 | 45643213 | 6 | 2021-05-07 |
| 3 | 2019/06/08 | 65437658 | 57647868 | 7 | 2020-06-07 |
| 3 | 2020/06/07 | 57647868 | 89067445 | 8 | 2021-05-07 |
| 3 | 2021/05/07 | 89067445 | 45643213 | 9 | 2021-05-07 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see there are a couple of issues with your formula.

First of all there is no relationship between `Table` and `DbEmployees` so when you are filtering exclusively on the dates, which might get you the wrong Location. This can be fixed by changing the formula to:

```
Location = 
VAR CurrentContractDate = [Sale Date]
VAR empName = [Name]
RETURN
VAR RespLocation =
            TOPN (
                1,
                FILTER(DbEmployees, DbEmployees[Name] = empName),
                IF (
                .....
```

Secondly, you need to remember that the `TOPN` function can return multiple rows, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/topn-function-dax#remarks):

> If there is a tie, in order_by values, at the N-th row of the table, then all tied rows are returned. Then, when there are ties at the N-th row the function might return more than n rows.

This can be fixed by picking the Max/Min of the result in the table:

```
RETURN MAXX(SELECTCOLUMNS( RespLocation,"Location", [Location] ), [Location])
```

Finally, I don't understand why the last row on the expected result should be a 3, given that the sale date is within a record with location 6.

Full expression:

```
Location = 
VAR CurrentContractDate = [Sale Date]
VAR empName = [Name]
RETURN
VAR RespLocation =
            TOPN (
                1,
                FILTER(DbEmployees, DbEmployees[Name] = empName),
                IF (
                    CurrentContractDate <= DbEmployees[EndDate]
                        && CurrentContractDate >= DbEmployees[StartDate], //Check, whether there is matching date
                    DATEDIFF ( DbEmployees[StartDate], DbEmployees[EndDate], DAY ), //If so, rank matching locations (you may want to employ a different formula)
                    MIN (  //If the location is not matching, calculate how close it is (from both start and end date)
                        ABS ( DATEDIFF ( CurrentContractDate, DbEmployees[StartDate], DAY ) ),
                        ABS ( DATEDIFF ( CurrentContractDate, DbEmployees[EndDate], DAY ) )
                    ) + 1000000 //Add a discriminating factor in case there are matching rows that should be favoured over non-matching.
                ), 1
            )
            RETURN
            MAXX(SELECTCOLUMNS( RespLocation,"Location", [Location] ), [Location])
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. There was a  typo in my dataset. I fixed it and your answer works as expected.